# Critical IIS 10 Event IDs in Event viewer

Tags: iis, iis-10, event-viewer, event-id

can anyone help me find a document/articles or blogs regarding the list of all critical event IDs for IIS web server version 10 with their description? I'm looking for hours and I can't seem to find a document regarding that. I've found a document from Microsoft but it's outdated and is on version 7.5 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364124(v=ws.10).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has not officially updated critical event IDs for IIS 10, but the previous documentation should be available.

What are you looking for critical event IDs for? Troubleshooting the problem? If yes, this link should help you: [Viewing IIS Event and Error Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524984(v=vs.90)).